# React-bootstrap, not closed modal window

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I use the standard 'useState' for closing Modal. As long as the form does not transmit information, everything works. But when on pressing the 'submit' button I pass the function for execution, the function is executed, and stops closing the modal window. My button's cod: onClick= {(e) => Auth.handle_login(e, state)}.

My code:

```
<Modal show={show} **onHide={handleClose}**>
<Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title> Вход </Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>
    <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId='fromBasicEmail'>
            <Form.Label> Email </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type='email' placeholder='Введите Email' />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Label>Пароль</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type='password' placeholder='Введите пароль' />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
            <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Запомнить меня"/>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className='mb-5' size="lg" block
        /*onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); alert('32')}}*/
        //onClick= {(e) => {Auth.handle_login(e, state); setModalStatus(false)}}
        **onClick= {(e) => Auth.handle_login(e, state)}**
        >Войти</Button>
        <Form.Text className='text-muted'>
            Ещё нет аккаунта? Зарегистрируйтесь
        </Form.Text>
    </Form>
</Modal.Body>
```

Comment: Did you try onClick= {(e) => {Auth.handle_login(e, state); handleClose()}} ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and got an error. I decided to double-check, copied and pasted your code and it worked! Thank you.